# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'learn_predicates'

Tags: python-dedupe

I have information about found doubles in table `learning`, where `entity_id` is the same for doubles. I want to teach Dedupe by example, but get error. What am I doing wrong?

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database=db_conf['NAME'],
                   user=db_conf['USER'],
                   password=db_conf['PASSWORD'],
                   host=db_conf['HOST'],
                   cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
con.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
c = con.cursor()
if os.path.exists(settings_file):
    print('reading from ', settings_file)
    with open(settings_file, 'rb') as sf:
        deduper = dedupe.StaticDedupe(sf, num_cores=4)
else:
     fields = [{'field': 'name', 'variable name': 'name',
               'type': 'String', 'has missing': True},

              {'field': 'address', 'type': 'Text',
               'variable name': 'address', 'has missing': True},

          {'type': 'Interaction',
           'interaction variables': ['name', 'address']}
          ]

    deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields, num_cores=8)

    LEARNING_QUERY = "SELECT entity_id, name, address FROM learning;"
    c.execute(LEARNING_QUERY) `

    temp_d = dict((i, row) for i, row in enumerate(c))
    deduper.markPairs(dedupe.trainingDataDedupe(temp_d, 'entity_id'))
    del temp_d   
    deduper.train()
```

ERROR:

```
/home/sontata/venv/bin/python /home/sontata/PycharmProjects/test/actual_object_learning.py
INFO:root:Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
INFO:root:Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
starting active labeling...
/home/sontata/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rlr/lr.py:39: UserWarning: The line-search routine reaches the maximum number of evaluations.
  case_weights, self.alpha))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sontata/PycharmProjects/test/actual_object_learning.py", line 110, in <module>
    deduper.train()
  File "/home/sontata/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dedupe/api.py", line 678, in train
    self.predicates = self.active_learner.learn_predicates(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'learn_predicates'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, I should have just added `deduper.sample(temp_d, 15000)` before  `deduper.markPairs`.